# app.js:9160 You are running the esm-bundler build of Vue. It is recommended to configure your bundler to explicitly replace feature flag globals wi

Tags: javascript, laravel, vue.js, webpack, laravel-mix

I'm running a Laravel 8/vue3/inertiajs app, created via `laravel new myappname` on the console (linux/chromebook).

i'm using `npm run hot` to run/test the app.

a warning shows up in the console:

> app.js:9160 You are running the esm-bundler build of Vue. It is
> recommended to configure your bundler to explicitly replace feature
> flag globals with boolean literals to get proper tree-shaking in the
> final bundle. See http://link.vuejs.org/feature-flags for more
> details.

there are some answers here on SO that talk about how to `webpack.DefinePlugin()` with these flags, but none seem to actually work with my default-ish setup.

In my app's home directory i have a `webpack.config.js` and a `webpack.mix.js`.

The webpack.mix.js is the following:

```
  1 const mix = require('laravel-mix');
  2 
  3 /*
  4  |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
  5  | Mix Asset Management
  6  |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
  7  |
  8  | Mix provides a clean, fluent API for defining some Webpack build steps
  9  | for your Laravel applications. By default, we are compiling the CSS
 10  | file for the application as well as bundling up all the JS files.
 11  |
 12  */
 13 
 14 mix.js('resources/js/app.js', 'public/js')
 15     .vue()
 16     .postCss('resources/css/app.css', 'public/css', [
 17         require('postcss-import'),
 18         require('tailwindcss'),
 19         require('autoprefixer'),
 20     ])
 21     .webpackConfig(require('./webpack.config'));
 22 
 23 
 24 if (mix.inProduction()) {
 25     mix.version();
 26 }
 27
```

The `webpack.config.js` is the following:

```
  1 const path = require('path');
  2 
  3 module.exports = {
  4     resolve: {
  5         alias: {
  6             '@': path.resolve('resources/js'),
  7         },
  8     },
  9 };
```

When i change my mix file to try to include the DefinePlugin config:

```
 15 mix.js('resources/js/app.js', 'public/js')
 16     .vue()
 17     .postCss('resources/css/app.css', 'public/css', [
 18         require('postcss-import'),
 19         require('tailwindcss'),
 20         require('autoprefixer'),
 21     ])
 22     .webpackConfig(
 23             {
 24               plugins: [
 25                 new webpack.DefinePlugin({
 26                   __VUE_OPTIONS_API__: false,
 27                   __VUE_PROD_DEVTOOLS__: false,
 28                 }),
 29               ],
 30             }
 31         );
 32     //.webpackConfig(require('./webpack.config'));
```

I get build errors when running `npm run dev`. And I get build errors with any permutation I can think to try - both files, include file in various configurations/formats/scopes/etc.

If I try to include that `require('.webpack.config')` line, I get this:

```
> development
> mix

[webpack-cli] /home/psmithsf/dev/ideatracker/webpack.mix.js:23
            require('./webpack.config');
                                      ^

SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list
    at new Script (node:vm:99:7)
```

In short, I'm stumped on how to include what is probably supposed to be a simple config option. It might just be a matter of seeing a working example of something with a standard laravel/mix setup.

...may have fixed at least part of my problem. I can get the `npm run dev` to compile, and the app will run and the original warning message will go away, but now i have some new warnings -- potentially related to just other things. ??

This is my updated `webpack.config.js`:

```
  1 const path = require('path');
  2 var webpack = require('webpack');
  3 
  4 module.exports = {
  5     resolve: {
  6         alias: {
  7             '@': path.resolve('resources/js'),
  8         },
  9     },
 10     plugins: [
 11         new webpack.DefinePlugin({
 12           __VUE_OPTIONS_API__: true,
 13           __VUE_PROD_DEVTOOLS__: false,
 14         }),
 15       ],
 16 };
 17
```

I tried this before, and it compiled, but got plenty of errors in my app's browser console.

I switched the **VUE_OPTIONS_API** to 'true' and most errors went away, and I'm left with only new warnings now.

Warning 1:

> backend.js:821    Instance uid=0:2 not found

Warning 2:

> jquery-3.6.0.min.js:2   [Violation] 'setTimeout' handler took 138ms

I'll consider this a self-answer soon after I verify I'm not putting junk out into the world.